# What is the reason for checking the environment when setting a Prisma utility class?

Tags: javascript, prisma

I was looking at a Prisma example today and saw the author recommended creating a utility class so that new connections aren't made with each import.  The code they suggested is this:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

export const prisma = global.prisma || new PrismaClient();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  global.prisma = prisma;
}
```

Wouldn't this code defeat the purpose in production and create a new connection each time?  Or does the "prisma" variable persist between imports, and is only global in non-production environments so you don't have to import it each time you want to use it?

Comment: perhaps you can link your source and quote the relevant part, for more context.

Comment: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/connection-management  I found a better explanation in the docs referenced above.  I was using Next.js and didn't realize the issue was caused by the hot reloading feature.